# memcached: item is not available in cache

Tags: django, memcached

I have an issue with memcached. I store values using string key with template 'question_%d_%d'. I have enought memory:

```
STAT bytes 13307757 
STAT limit_maxbytes 134217728
```

but here is a log of my application:

```
2012-01-03 16:40:42,896 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache miss
2012-01-03 18:03:10,270 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache miss
2012-01-03 22:26:16,454 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache miss
2012-01-04 02:01:54,639 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache miss
2012-01-04 02:45:03,647 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache miss
2012-01-04 02:46:55,880 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache hit
2012-01-04 02:51:55,606 Get question for key question_4_1045: cache miss
```

so we can see, that two sequential calls with the same key lead to two cache misses, and only once value is fetched from cache.

Why memcached removes my data from cache, even if there is enough space? Is it possible to fix it?

I tried to check my memcached log file (according to config file it is  /var/log/memcached.log), but it is empty.
Thanks!

UPD:
Django cache settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT': 259200,
    }
}

CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'
```

getter:

```
from django.core.cache import cache    
def get_question(level, random_num):
        key = 'question_' + unicode(level) + '_' + unicode(random_num)
        question = cache.get(key)
        if question is None:
            question = Question.objects.filter(level=level).order_by('id')[random_num]
            cache.set(key, question)
            log_message('Get question for key %s: cache miss' % key)
        else:
            log_message('Get question for key %s: cache hit' % key)
        return question
```

Comment: How can anyone help with this without seeing the code for the cache set and get?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I've updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I saw the root cause of the problem.
I had a cache config for Django 1.2 in my settings.py (I use django 1.2):

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'
```

When I decided to change timeout I copy-pasted timeout settings from new Django docs for Django 1.3. So these timeout settings were just ignored and default timeout (5 min) was used.